# Accessing Snow leopard from remote

Tags: remote-desktop, unix

I have a snow leopard computer in a remote location, logged out. I want to be able to use this machine from a Linux computer. I already hear you saying vnc, but vnc works only for a logged in session. The remote machine is logged out, and must stay this way. Occasionally, someone else may login to it with a different username.

How can I start a remote OSX session from Linux ?

Comment: did it work? :)

Answer (score 1):

www.logmein.com is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Lion is the first Mac OS to let a second person log in via VNC when a different user is logged in. You could have the local account log in automatically and then lock the screen with a password so that the remote people can get to their login screen rather than the "local" account.

Snow Leopard and earlier OS don't have the hooks to spawn off a second graphical interface. Some people have hacked X and used Xnest to make virtual screens, but it's not the true Apple graphical environment that is running.